# Matlab: PDE toolbox, get length of each element on the boundary

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde

I setup and meshed a domain using Matlab's PDE toolbox. Along the boundary, is there someway to get the length of each element of the mesh? And the flux in the normal direction? (the bc are Dirichlet)

[image: Example mesh]

Edit:

See example code

```
RMax = 20;
RL = 1;
RU = 0.5;
HN = 5;
HL = 2;
HTT = 3;
HU = 1.5;
VL = -150;
p = [RL,0;RL,HN;0,HN+HL;0,HN+HL+HTT;RU,HN+HL+HTT+HU;RMax,HN+HL+HTT+HU;RMax,0];

t = [1;1;0;1;1;0;0];
v = [VL;VL;0;0;0;0;0];

dx = 0.5;
dy = 0.5;

bc = cell(size(t));

for i = 1:length(t)
    if t(i) == 0
        bc{i} = {'u', v(i)};
    elseif t(i) == 1
        bc{i} = {'g', v(i), 'q', 1};
    else
        error('Unrecognized boundary condition type.')
    end
end

model = createpde;

gd = [2; size(p,1); p(:,1) ; p(:,2)];
ns = char('domain')';
sf = 'domain';

g = decsg(gd,sf,ns);
geometryFromEdges(model,g);

generateMesh(model, 'Hmax', min([dx,dy])/3, 'MesherVersion','R2013a');

for i = 1:size(bc,1)
    applyBoundaryCondition(model, 'Edge', i, bc{i}{:});
end

u = assempde( model , 'x' , 0 , 0 );

pdemesh(model)
```

Edit: 2015-12-17 18:54 GMT

There are 2 points in the `e` shown at `1` and `2` in the figure below. I want to know the coordinate of `3` so I know which direction is into the domain.

[image: Example with points]

Comment: It would help if you included example code that you used to mesh your domain and plot the result

Answer (score 2):

You can answer your first question by using [`meshToPet`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/meshtopet.html) to convert to [[P,E,T] form](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/mesh-data.html#buqc5wy-1):

```
[p,e,t] = meshToPet(model.Mesh);
x1 = p(1,e(1,:)); % x-coordinates of first point in each mesh edge
x2 = p(1,e(2,:)); % x-coordinates of second point in each mesh edge
y1 = p(2,e(1,:)); % y-coordinates of first point in each mesh edge
y2 = p(2,e(2,:)); % y-coordinates of second point in each mesh edge

% Plot first points of mesh edge
plot(x1,y1,'b.-',x1(1),y1(1),'go',x1(end),y1(end),'ro');

% Euclidean distance between first and second point in each edge
d = sqrt((x1-x2).^2+(y1-y2).^2);
```

I'm assuming you just want the lengths of the mesh edge/boundary. You can use similar methods to get the lengths of every single triangle using the `t` matrix.

As far as flux goes, there's [`pdecgrad`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pdecgrad.html). I think the following may work:

```
...
c = 'x';
u = assempde(model, c, 0, 0);
[p,e,t] = meshToPet(model.Mesh);
[cgxu,cgyu] = pdecgrad(p,t,c,u);
```

Comment: Thank you. For the flux, I'm looking to the normal flux u_n = u_x cos(theta) + u_y sin(theta). However, I need to know the third point of the elements on the boundary to get the correct normal direction. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the third point of the elements on the boundary"?